# Spark 3.3.0 or greater than 3.3.0 versions giving class not found with json4s library

Tags: json4s

json4s version tried with 3.6.10 , 4.1.0-M4
scala version 2.12.15
jdk version jdk 17

I was upgrading my java based application which uses scala and spark also json4s for some processing we are migrating from java 1.8 to java 17.  facing issue during deployment
The error says java.lang.classnotfoundexception: org.json4s.jsonassoc$ exception if I use json4s-jackson_2.12 less than 4.0.0 but when i am using json4s-jackson_2.12 greater than ver 4.0.0 I am getting error as
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue]
Since i need to use java 17
So i have to use scala 2.12.15+ if using scala 2.12.x
As per the scala jdk compatibility matrix
The issue seems to be with spark and json4s-jackson library incompatibility can someone help with this and guide me which spark version is compatible with json4s-jackson_2.12 libray using scala 2.12.15 , jdk 17

if i use json4s-jackson_2.12 ver 4.0.6 or above i get following error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
... 95 more

if i use spark version 3.3.0 i have json4s-jackson_2.12 ver 3.6.10 which gives this error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json4s.JsonAssoc$
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)

not sure which json4s will work for java 17 scala 2.12.15 and spark 3.3.0 or higher